# Wordpress on ECS - cannot connect to mysql container

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to install a Wordpress on ECS using the task definition from here :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html . I have the following task on ECS (2 containers) - json format :

```
{
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::548086034478:role/wpstream-ecsTaskExecution",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/wordpress-simple",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "command": null,
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 0,
            "environment": [],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": null,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "wordpress",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": [
                "mysql"
            ],
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "wordpress"
        },
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/wordpress-simple",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [],
            "command": null,
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 0,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "cretu"
                }
            ],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": null,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "mysql",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "mysql"
        }
    ],
    "memory": "512",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::548086034478:role/wpstream-ecsTaskExecution",
    "family": "wordpress-simple",
    "pidMode": null,
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "cpu": "256",
    "inferenceAccelerators": [],
    "proxyConfiguration": null,
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "tags": []
}
```

But for some reason the worpdress container cannot connect to mysql container. When i access it via the public ip i get a "Error establishing a database connection" and in the logs

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

I try adding the WORDPRESS_DB_HOST,WORDPRESS_DB_USER,WORDPRESS_DB_NAME and WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD environment variables on wordpress container but with no luck.

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issues was caused by the new mysql version(8.0) who change the authentication method. The solution is either to use an older mysql image (5.17) or to use this command on container creation

default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password